# Error : undefined reference to `freopen'

Tags: c, file-io

When I use `fopen` and execute a C code, I dont get any error. But when I use `freopen` I get

`(.text+0x2c054): undefined reference to 'freopen'`

Both being in the same `stdio.h` library, how is this possible?

Comment: Can we see some code?

Comment: What compiler are you using and how are ou linking the files with each other?

Comment: I'm using gnu gcc compiler. I use `makefile`

Comment: using GCC, it can be very fussy about parameter type matching with the prototype in the header file.  Please post actual code around where freopen is invoked.